# What is the point of "return" in afterSave handler in Parse

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, back4app

I'm confused as to what the purpose of the return keyword is in afterSave handlers. As far as I know it does not return the result to the client , if so then where is it returning the result to? Pic from Cloud Code documentation give below for reference.

[image]

Comment: This code is not about returning a result it is about a chain process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code example above, which I think is from the docs, the return ensures that any error from `post.save()` will get 'caught' by the `catch`.

In an `afterSave` hook, no error will ever be returned to the client.  The object that will be returned is unaffected by anything that happens in the `afterSave`.

What is influenced by the return in the `afterSave` is when the connection to the client will be closed.

If you return a promise, the connection will *not* be closed until the promise resolves. In the case of the code you cite, the promise is not returned so the connection will be closed immediately because the `afterSave` function will return before the post.save() promise is resolved.

In order for the `return` that you highlighted to have any impact to the client, you'd also have to return the query like so:

```js
Parse.Cloud.afterSave('Comment', (request) => {
    const query = new Parse.Query('Post');
    return query.get(....)
```

In which case, the client would wait for the post's comment count to be incremented and saved before the connection is closed.

Read on to understand why this matters and other fine points about `afterSave` and how 'returning' works!

Here are some considerations:

1. If you are going to do some 'expensive' or long operations and the client does not need to wait, then make sure you do not return a promise and that the `afterSave` function is not `async`.  This would be appropriate if you wanted to update an external system or send an email as a result of the save.  Here's an example of how to disconnect...

```js
const afterSave = function afterSave(request) {
  const { object } = request;
  got.post('htttps://my.microservice/complete', { object })
    .then(() => console.log('done posting to microservice'))
    .catch(console.error);
};
```

If there is an error posting to the 'microservice', the client will never know, but it will be logged to your console.

2. A case where it is appropriate to make the client wait for the `afterSave` is a case where you need to make sure that a related operation completes before the client gets the saved object back.  For example, imagine that your need to add a new user to a role and that that operation needs to be completed before returning the user to the client or an error will occur due to lack of permissions.  In this case, you need the user to be saved, which gives it an id, before you can add her to a role.  So, in this case, you would add the user to the role in the `afterSave` which is an async operation and return the resulting promise so that the state of the user's permission will be set and known when the client gets the returned user object.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Arthur
You posted this on Mar 27, 2020. At first, almost everything went over my head. So I kept learning more about JS and Parse and kept coming back to your explanation. Slow but surely I started understanding it. And now after a whole YEAR, I finally get it. Thank you for the amazing explanation.

Comment: You are welcome.  As I'm sure you can now appreciate, writing it out helped me too :).